# How to Remove Line Underneath Table

Tags: html, css, iframe

Hello could anybody please help me remove this underline at the bottom of my table. Here is my code,

```
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>

<td><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99496559" width="220" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><a href="http://vimeo.com/99496559"><b><span style="font-size: small;">Daniel talks about the Austplan model</span></b></a>.</td>
<td><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99582077" width="220" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><a href="http://vimeo.com/99582077"><b><span style="font-size: small;">Peace of mind Building Relationships</span></b></a>.</td>
<td><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99579066" width="220" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><a href="http://vimeo.com/99579066"><b><span style="font-size: small;">Talk About Who Is Daniel Renneberg</span></b></a>.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Screenshot of the problem: [image: http://i.imgur.com/fpESDza.png]

Comment: show your css or page url

Comment: Use `div`s instead of a table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snb5oxmw/

Answer (score -1):

If this coming from your table border then you can hide border using:

```
<table border="0">
```

If not, then check if there is any `<hr />` tag contains in your code.